# React this.state is undefined in component function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

function `typeContactGetter` is binded to this and everything is working, the only issue is in the functions return on the `<li>` element, I am trying to set a className coming from state and it returns undefined for `this.state`.

Why is this happening?

Thanks,
Bud

### component

```
class ContactType extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date(),
            hiddenList: false,
            familyContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Family"),
            friendContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Friends")
        };
        this.typeContactGetter = this.typeContactGetter.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.hideList = this.hideList.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked, state: ' + this.state.hiddenList);
    };

    hideList = () => {
        console.log("this is hidelist: " + this.state.hiddenList);
        if (this.state.hiddenList === true){
            this.setState({
                hiddenList: false
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            hiddenList: !this.state.hiddenList
        });
    };

    typeContactGetter = (name) => {
        console.log(this.state);
        for (let contact of CONTACTS) {
            if (contact.name === name) {
                return (
                    <li  className={this.state.hiddenList ? 'hidden' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick} key={contact.id.toString()}>
                        {contact.contacts.map(value => {
                            if (value.type === "Contact") {
                                return (
                                    <a key={value.id.toString()} href="#">{value.name}</a>
                                );
                            }
                        })
                        }
                    </li>
                );
            }
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <ContactView familyContacts={this.state.familyContacts} friendContacts={this.state.friendContacts} hideList={this.hideList}/>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactType;
```

Comment: you are invoking ```typeContactGetter``` function before binding it to ```this``` in your constructor. try setting states on ```familyContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Family"),
            friendContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Friends")``` on componentDidMount

Comment: what part of state is undefined

Comment: @NoushadPP typeContactGetter is an arrow. It shouldn't be bound at all.

Comment: @estus - your right, removed bind from typeContactGetter , still this.state isn't defined, what should I do to have this.state in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you call `typeContactGetter` in the constructor before the state is actually created.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        date: new Date(),
        hiddenList: false,
        familyContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Family"), // hey, but we are actually creating the state right now
        friendContacts: this.typeContactGetter("Friends")
    };
}
```

Why do you want to keep a component list in the state? Maybe it is better to pass them directly:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        date: new Date(),
        hiddenList: false,
    };
}

....

<ContactView familyContacts={this.typeContactGetter("Family")} friendContacts={this.typeContactGetter("Friends")} hideList={this.hideList}/>
```

btw you don't need to bind function as they are bound already by arrow functions.